# How do I bind to s-up?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to do this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-up") 'beginning-of-buffer)
```

and I get this error

```
error "s- must prefix a single character, not up"
```

How do I tell it to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Named keys should be written in angle brackets like this:

```
(kbd "s-<up>")
```

The exceptions to this are `RET`, `SPC`, `TAB`, `DEL`, `LFD`, `ESC`, and `NUL`, which must be in uppercase.  See the documentation for `edmacro-mode` (<kbd>C-h f edmacro-mode</kbd>) for a more complete explanation of the syntax `kbd` accepts.

Also note that the `s-` prefix is for the super modifier, and `S-` is for shift.

Answer (score 6):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<up>") 'beginning-of-buffer)
```